# How can I have multiple pages of one ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I currently have one long ListView in my android application and I would like to separate that one ListView into multiple pages so that when the user selects the next button, that will be in the actionbar, it goes to the next set of ListView items.

How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own ListAdapter/ArrayAdapter and have it only load the items you want to. The arrayadapter is good and easy enough to use.

[ArrayAdapter example](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/how-to-create-a-listview-using-arrayadapter-in-android/),
[here is another example](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1659127&q=binding-android-listview-with-string-array-using-arrayadapter)